# Enabled AD Group Members of multiple groups

Tags: powershell-ise

I'm trying to get only enabled members which are in multiple groups but not sure how to achieve this in the format I want. My current script is as follows.

```
$GroupList = @('GroupA','GroupB'
 )

$Groupusers  = @()

foreach ($Groups in $GroupList)
{

    $Groupusers += Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Groups | select @{Name="Groups";Expression={$Groups}},name
}

$Groupusers | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Me\Documents\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

The above script works and formats the output for what I am after but this also includes even the disabled users.

Output:

Group                 name

---

GroupA               UserA
GroupB               UserB

I have tried the following script, this gives me the all the enabled user but not in a format like the above script.

```
$groupname = @('GroupA', 'GroupB')

$Groupusers=@()


foreach ($group in $groupname)
{

    $Groupusers += Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | ? {$_.objectclass -eq "user"}
}

$result= @()

foreach ($activeusers in $Groupusers) 

{ 

$result += (Get-ADUser -Identity $activeusers | ? {$_.enabled -eq $true} | select Name, Enabled) 

}

$result
```

How can I achieve the output above but with only enabled users?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the formatting of the first script, this should work for you.  Just create a second array to hold only the $groupusers who are enabled, and write just that subset to your output file.

```
$GroupList = @('GroupA','GroupB')

$Groupusers  = @()

foreach ($Groups in $GroupList)
{

    $Groupusers += Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Groups | select @{Name="Groups";Expression={$Groups}},name  
    
}

$activeusers = @()
foreach ($user in $Groupusers)
{
$n = $user.name
$props = get-aduser -filter "name -eq '$n'" | select samaccountname, enabled
  if ($props.enabled)
  {

    $activeusers += $user
  }
}

$activeusers | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Me\Documents\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

Comment: I’m sure this could be streamlined, but I think it does what you’re asking for.